# Determine if a hash is a nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a way to determine if a hash is a nested hash in ruby ?

For example

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
```

should return false

```
a = { a: {a1: 1, a2: 2}, b: {b1: 1}, c: 2 }
```

should return true

Comment: What if `h = { :a => [{ :b = 3 }] }`?

Comment: hmm thats an edge case I haven't considered. For my problem it shouldn't be possible though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.any? { |_, v| v.is_a?(Hash) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by iterating over your hash values with [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values) method:

```
a.values.any? { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) }
```

Comment: This reads well, but better to use [Hash#each_value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) to avoid the creation of a temporary array.